# vue3-select2-component, filter by first characters

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to filter options('sorter' in settings work fine) but i can't to get modelValue from 'input' that i type any symbols in. How can i get the first symbols that i typed ?
Work only event @select but it is not suitable for this task

```
<Select2
  value="modelValue"
  @input="(e) => modelValue = e.target.value"
  :settings="select2Settings"
/>
select2Settings: {
  sorter: function (results) {
    return results.filter((item) => item.text.startsWith(modelValue))
  }
}
```

Also i tried use event @change but it doesn't work at all
[in this demo](https://github.com/godbasin/vue-select2/tree/demo-for-vue3-select-component)

Comment: maybe rewrite this component...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work fine!

```
select2Settings: {
    matcher: function (params, data) {
      if (!params.term)
        return data;
      if (data.text.toLowerCase().startsWith(params.term.toLowerCase()))
        return data;
      else
        return null;
    },
}
```